# Unable to install JDK7u21x64 on Windows 8 x64

Tags: windows-8, installation, java, java-7

I have just upgraded to Windows 8 Pro, mostly because my Windows 7 license has reached maximum activations and I have a free copy of 8, and partially so I can ensure my software is 8-compatible.

I seem to be incapable of installing the JDK. I just downloaded it from the Oracle website (jdk-7u21-windows-x64.exe).

Windows reports itself as: 64-bit Operating System, x64-based processor.

When I try and run it, either normally or as administrator is shows up with the message:

> **This app can't run on your PC**
>
> To find a version for your PC, check with the software publisher

Does anyone have any ideas on this, a quick Google indicates it should just install same as usual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While 8 still insistently refuses to install the JDK even after re-downloading and checking the hash, the Netbeans + JDK bundle does install which includes the JDK so that solves this issue sufficiently for now.

Update: The 64-bit version now works fine.

Comment: You can uninstall Netbeans afterwards, and keep just the JDK.

Answer (score 0):

Try the x86 version: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html , I don't think there is a proper build for Windows 8 Pro.